# Implementing Lights on a robot

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I'm trying to implement a light on a robot to replicate a laser pointer dot in the scene. Is there a way to do this so that a camera will be able to pick it up, and so that it moves with a robot link as if attached?

I tried implementing a spotlight but gazebo wouldn't recognise my links as being valid references for the light. Has anyone been able to do this?

cheers

Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6486/implementing-lights-on-a-robot/) by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 203 on 2014-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

That feature isn't currently present. Please [upvote the existing feature request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/900/allow-attachment-of-lights-to-links) in the gazebo issue tracker. If you have any thoughts about the implementation, feel free to add them there as well.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0